# Probabilities sum > 1

Tags: probability

$s_{1} = {1,2}$

$s_{1} = {3,4}$

As underlined in this doc taken from http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html:

[image]

$
P\left( x\varepsilon s_{1}\right)+P\left( x\varepsilon s_{2}\right) > 1
$

In this Venn diagram

$$
S_{1}\cap S_{2}=\emptyset
$$

:

[image]

What are conditions for $
P\left( x\in s_{1}\right)+P\left( x\in s_{2}\right) > 1
$ as regardless of value I assign x : 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 $
P\left( x\in s_{1}\right)+P\left( x\in s_{2}\right) 
$ is always <= 1 ?

Comment: Use \emptyset and \in

Comment: The sets need to be constructed from uncountably many elements; they use a continuum of Real numbers, rather than a set of discrete Integers.

Also, examine the [Banach-Tarski Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) as suggested.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, if the $s_i$ are nonmeasurable, $P(x\in s_i)$ does not makes sense.

Comment: Yes, as indicated in the opening statement, this is an issue that Measure Theory has been *developed* to make resolve. @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Measure theory is beyond the scope of this textbook...

Indeed, because $P(x\in s_i)$ only makes sense if the sets $s_i$ are *measurable*. The sets in the Banach-Tarski paradox are *nonmeasurable*.

Nonmeasurable sets aren't fractals in any meaningful sense and I can't fathom what means "transforming the set of rational numbers".